# Native zoom of smart phone camera in a Vue.js web app

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, camera, zooming, smartphone

I am developing a web application with Vue.js 2. The application will run only in smartphone browsers (small screens). The application uses the smartphone's camera for photos and a video. Before I take a photo, I want to be able to zoom in or out (pinch-to-zoom). After I have started shooting the video, while I'm filming, I also want to be able to zoom in or out (with fingers). So, in any case, I want the native behavior of the smartphone's camera to take place in my web app. I don't want anything on the page to zoom except the photo (respectively, video) area. Is there a simple solution for this?